# Reading JSON Data with inconsistent data index extJS

Tags: json, extjs, chef-infra

I am currently trying to read data from an endpoint on my Chef Server using the `JSON` proxy reader in **ExtJS** in order to display it on a grid.

> Usually the `JSON` response looks something like this:

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optioreprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
}, {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
}
```

---

However, the response I am receiving from the endpoint, specifically, the `organizations/(organization-name)/cookbooks` endpoint

> comes in like this:

```
{
    "my_cookbook_1": {
        "url": "company.com",
        "versions": [{
            "version": "0.1.0",
            "url": "company.com"
        }]
    }
}, {
    "my_cookbook_2": {
        "url": "company.com",
        "versions": [{
            "version": "0.2.0",
            "url": "company.com"
        }]
    }
}
```

---

With the former response, I can specify the `dataIndex` attribute on the grid as `name` and get the respective information.

```
var optionalCookbooksGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: optionalCookbooksStore,
    width: '100%',
    height: 200,
    title: 'Optional Cookbooks',
    columns: [{
        text: 'Role',
        width: 100,
        sortable: false,
        hideable: false,
        dataIndex: 'userID'
    }]
});
```

Because my response from the Chef Server does not have a consistent `dataIndex`.

How would I display the content to my `grid`?

Comment: What are you looking to display in your grid? Is it a concatenated array all the `versions` under each key?

Comment: I would like to just display the cookbook name on the grid but possibly have it so that if I click on a row on that grid, I can display more properties of that cookbook respective to its JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing of extJS so this isn't really a direct answer, but then again this isn't really a Chef question either. Basically the Chef REST API is not built for direct consumption by simple clients. Notably the list endpoint you showed there only gives the name (and URL but that's pretty useless) for each cookbook. From there you need to do N more queries to grab the list of versions for each and then possibly N*M to grab the details for each version. You would normally do this all before feeding the resulting massive data blob in to a UI framework.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Some pre-processing will have to be done before displaying it to my view. I was hoping for something better but if that is the case, as it seems to be, then so be it. Thank you